# Adding latest icon in data grid view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datagridview, icons

I have display the data from the data table in View.aspx interface using data grid view. So now I have done sorting but I don't know how to add icon for the latest data in the data grid view row. Can I add "latest" icon in data grid view for the latest announcement ? Is it possible ? How should I do it ?

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (ViewState["dtbl1"] != null) 
    { 
        DataTable dtbl = (DataTable)ViewState["dtbl1"]; 
        DataView dv = new DataView(dtbl); dv.Sort = e.SortExpression; 
        GridView1.DataSource = dv; GridView1.DataBind(); 
    } 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of latest? Announced today? Announced during last week? Announced during last month? Can you share the code of how are you loading and soring the data in the GridView?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Announced today 
This is the code ::::

       protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["dtbl1"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtbl = (DataTable)ViewState["dtbl1"];
                DataView dv = new DataView(dtbl);
                dv.Sort = e.SortExpression;
                GridView1.DataSource = dv;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }

Comment: You need to share your code in the question itself. You can edit the question and add new details/code to it. Code in comments is not readable. You can use TemplateColumn for displaying any customer contents in the GridView column....

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Why uh its showing error when i upload the code in the question ? Do u know why ? I'm new to this platform btw

Comment: Are you trying to upload the code files to the question? You need to write the code in the question. There is no need to upload code or project file to the question,

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I 've uploaded the source code